# Get the Sum of Values in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

```
data: {
   goodReceiveNote:{ id:1,netTotal: null}
   poDetailsList:[
     0:{id:1,subTotal:300},
     1:{id:1,subTotal:200}
   ]
}
```

How to get the sum of poDetailsList subTotal and Assign it to the netTotal in goodReceiveNote in react.

Comment: add the numbers, assign it to the key!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the array reduce in combinaison with Object.values

```
const total = Object.values(data.poDetailsList).reduce((a,b) => a + b.subTotal, 0)
```