# sum duplicate array values and then storing them [react js]

Tags: reactjs, sorting, slice

I have an array that I want to write a function that get sum price of items that have same name  like:
jack=400
helen=200
and finally sort them

```js
const data = [
  {name: jack,prix:100},
  {name:helen,prix:200},
  {name:jack,prix:300}
]
```

Comment: and what method you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the Sum of Values in React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70161435/get-the-sum-of-values-in-react-js)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the desired output like below.

```js
const data = [
  { name: "jack", prix: 100 },
  { name: "helen", prix: 200 },
  { name: "jack", prix: 300 },
];

const output = data.reduce((prev, { name, prix }) => {
  prev[name] = prev[name] ? prev[name] + prix : prix;
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```